# How to know if ISP network have multiple routes

Tags: isp, redundancy, failover, route

When it is time to choose an ISP in a remote area, I hope that the chosen ISP is having an acceptable redundancy in his network.

Is there any way to verify all different route an ISP is having in his network ?

For sure when asking to ISP representative, they tell you they provide reliable service with redundancy, but is there any tool that allow use to check if an ISP is having several route in there network?

Even if I provision two ISP, that does not necessary provide me a good redundancy if they both run their fiber on the same network post.

It is my first time posting here.  I tried finding answers in existing answers without any luck.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I do this type of research using a number of different publicly available "route servers" or "looking glasses." Simply do a web search for "public bgp looking glass" and you should find a significant number of results.

Many of these tools now have a web interface you can access, although some are still network devices you can telnet/ssh into to run queries directly (if you know what you are doing). It would help to have some basic understanding of BGP command output, but for a number of tools, this isn't necessary.

You will need to determine an IP address used by the ISP network or the BGP ASN number of the ISP in question. Using the BGP routing information, you should be able to determine if the ISP has multiple peers. Each tool will likely work a bit differently and will often give you different results based on their own "unique" viewpoint of the Internet (i.e. where they are connected, where the target is located, which networks exist between the two, etc).

As an example, you can use the [Hurricane Electric Looking Glass website](https://lg.he.net/) to perform a query based on an IP address. Select a source router, choose the "BGP route" command, and enter the IP address. The results should be displayed in a table after you press the "Probe" button. In the "Path" column, should be the ASN path to the destination IP.

Clicking on that ASN get you further information about the AS. This information is contained in a number of tabs, the ones you are most likely interested in would be "Peers v4" and "Peers v6". This will provide a list of what HE has determined are the peers of the AS in question.

Answer (score 0):

Good ISPs document their peering capacity. For their public IX peerings (and some private ones), you can query several open databases like e.g. https://www.peeringdb.com (do check out YLearn's comment below regarding reliability of this information).

Even more important is their internal network design including resilience and redundancy - that however isn't usually disclosed and is extremely hard to gauge.

Comment: I must point out that resources such as peeringdb are not entirely reliable (end users must opt in and keep records updated/accurate). It is not required for any peering arrangement to be disclosed publicly in any way and they often are not.